# How can I escape my application.html.erb file

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have built a 'web app' using ruby 2.1.5 on rails 4.2.0.

What I want now is a single-page landing-page. I don't want this landing page to be influenced by any other existing css files that I have in my stylesheets layout.

The landing page (ideally) uses a css file named freelancer.css and the rest of my site uses default.css.

So in short; how can I specifically call a stylesheet for a single view/controller while escaping the rest of my css/scss files for the rest of my app.

The landing page has its own controller named Welcome.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render layout: false
  end
end
```

I have defined a custom route.

```
  authenticated :user do
    root 'pages#home', as: "authenticated_root"
  end
  root 'welcome#index'
```

And my Welcome controller's index is as such.

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <%= favicon_link_tag 'notes.png' %>
        <title>Balern Edu.</title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <script src='assets/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script src='assets/fullcalendar.js'></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/fullcalendar.css'>

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
```

My application.css.scss file:

```
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require 'masonry/transitions'
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require_tree .
 */
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap/theme';
@import 'chosen';
@import 'image-select';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `render layout: false`, you can use `layout: "welcome"` at the top of your `WelcomeController`, where the layout page is called `welcome.html.erb`. There, you can call whatever stylesheets you want.

Comment: I have made those changes, however I am seeing a navbar, that is in my layouts directory. I don't want the welcome.html.erb landing-page to know about those css files, just the one called freelancer.css.scss. So I want to remove all the partials, navs, css, etc. and want the entire welcome.html.erb basically to have just an empty html.file (in regards to its content).

Comment: Did you create a file called `welcome.html.erb` in the `layouts` view folder? Can you edit your question to include the contents of that file?

Comment: I believe you are right, I didn't implement everything properly as your said. Your answer helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can include css or JavaScript file only for custom page putting this code in your custom view:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "posts" %>
  <% stylesheet_link_tag "posts" %>
<% end %>
```

Also you need to put this code in **application.html.erb**:

```
<head>
  <%= yield :head %>
</head>
```